# Creating a ciruit based on specific entries

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

As homework, I have to draw an electrical circuit containing resistors in series and parallel based on the data calculated in the lab. We mesured the electric resistance of each individual connectors of the box. The box contains six different connectors. We also know that there are five resistors of 66 $\Omega$ (I have concluded this based on the results.) My biggest problem is to link the output 3 and 5 and 6. In fact, based on my results: [image]

I'm having a problem to sketch the three resistors in series. In fact, based on the table on the left, for 3-5, I should have three resistors but for 3-6, only two. My issue here is that 1-6 has a direct route and that 5-6 needs 2 resistors the same amount of resistors of 3-6...

If it could probably help you, here is my work already done, but it is not working... Also to mention that there is no connection between the red wires and the blue ones.

Could anyone guide me resolving this issue? I'm looking for tips mostly for the placement of my three resistors in series.
[image]

Comment: "the number of Ω that was passing": ohms don't pass.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano You're right, it is the current, I've edited my question!

Comment: Is it a given there are "five identical resistors", or "N identical resistors" - your statement _We also know that there are five resistors of 66 Ω (I have concluded this based on the results.)_ is ambiguous.

Comment: It would make a lot of sense if you have 100 ohm resistors... because 100 in parallel with 200 makes 66, three 100's in parallel makes 33,  etc.

Comment: @Floris :), Yes, it makes more sense. In fact, I successfully drew my circuit using 100 $\Omega$ resistors. There are three resistors in parallel, and one single at 3 and 5!

Comment: Yes - I had figured that out - hence my comment. But in line with the homework policy I didn't want to give you the answer... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the resistance between 1 and 6 is zero, as is the resistance between 2 and 4, you really have a four terminal problem.

Now you can draw the "equivalent resistance" of a four terminal device with just six resistors: if you put the terminals in a square, these six resistors form a square with the diagonals connected.

[image]

This leaves you with six values to solve for - and luckily, you have six independent equations. Solve for the six resistances, and you will solve your problem. You could just solve size equations with six unknowns, but there are some tricks to speed this up - look for pairs of terminals that must have an open connection between them.

See if that gets you there; let me know if you are still stuck after trying this.

Comment: But my problem is not the value of the resistance, it is the position of each resistance in the circuit. Moreover, my circuit must contain 5 identical resistors. Nevertheless, you made me realized that I can reduce my sketch to 4 terminals, I will explore this way!